# SQL, Determine if Records in Table A exist in Table B

Tags: sql

TableA has columns AccountNum and RoutingNum

TableB also has columns AccountNum and RoutingNum

Table B is more trustworthy. So, I would like to find if all records in Table A exist in Table B. And if not, which records do not match.

Is this on the right track? Your solution would be greatly appreciated.

```
select * 
from TableA a 
where a.AccountNum not in (select b.AccountNum from TableB)
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists`. The following query gives you all records in `tablea` that cannot be found in `tableb`:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from tableb b 
    where a.accountNum = b.accountNum and a.routingNum = b.routingNum
)
```

This assumes that you want to match on both columns (which is what your description suggests). You can adapt the `where` conditions in the subquery to match on one column only.

Comment: Thanks, what is the purpose of 'select 1'?

Comment: @NikoSenkov: it basically discards the results of trhe subquery. All we want to know is if *some row* was returned, we don't actually need the results.

Comment: @NikoSenkov `NOT EXISTS` checks if the result set of the subquery is empty. In this case `1` produces a result set with 1 row and 1 column, when the there's matching data in `tableb`.